# Fronting two tomcat Servers with Apache HTTP server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, tomcat7, redirect

I am trying to host the two different context (on 2 different tomcat servers) under the same domain. The contexts are related and should be hosted under same domain name. 
Lets say http://test.com/test1 and http://test.com/test2.

The apache http server already routing the internet traffic to http://test.com/test1 using the below configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
   ServerName test.com
   ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy balancer://test1Bal>
   BalancerMember ajp://tomcat1_host:8009/tomcat1
</Proxy>
    ProxyPass /test1/ balancer://test1Bal/
    ProxyPass / balancer://test1Bal/    
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way if i hit the URL http://test.com/test2, the apache http server should serve the pages/requests from the tomcat2 server ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a only a single node, you can remove the balancer. You also don't need the `ProxyPass` line that is redirecting `/`.

Use the following configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
   ServerName test.com
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPass /test1/ ajp://tomcat1_host:8009/tomcat1
   ProxyPass /test2/ ajp://tomcat2_host:8009/tomcat2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked well except that I had to remove / after test1 and test2 !     ProxyPass /test1 ajp://tomcat1_host:8009/tomcat1
   ProxyPass /test2 ajp://tomcat2_host:8009/tomcat2